# Slide div open after others have closed

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, slidedown, slideup

I think it's not that difficult a problem for someone experienced in jquery, but unfortunately, i'm not. I did search around, found some problems alike, but i couldn't connect the dots in the solutions mentioned.

```
<div id="Top">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
 <ul class="links">
  <li class="one"><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li class="two"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li class="three"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
 </ul>      
</div>

<div id="one">
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div id="two">
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div id="three">
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

So, i've got a div called "top", at the bottom of that div, i'm displaying three links, one,two and three. Beneath that div, there are 3 other div's, all on display:none, i want to show those div's if one of the corresponding links is clicked.
But, i only want to show a div AFTER an open one has closed. At this moment, one is closing while the other one is opening.

I tried a number of things, but none of them worked out. I hope someone can help me with a solution i can understand!

As a novice, i probably take the wrong route, but anyway, things i tried:

```
$("li.one a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#one").slideToggle( "slow", function(){
        $("#two, #three").slideUp( "slow" );
    });
});
```

This is only for li.one a, the same for li.two a and li.three a

And i tried like this:

```
$("li.een a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if( $( "#een" ).hasClass( "open" ) ) {
        $("#een").slideUp( "slow" ).removeClass("open");
    }
    else {
        $("#een").slideDown( "slow" ).addClass("open");
    };

});
```

Ok, i looked at Gal's answer and made this:

```
$("li.one a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#two').slideUp(function(){
        $('#one').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

And i put these in so two and three can slide open

```
$("li.two a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#two").slideToggle( "slow" );
});

$("li.three a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#three").slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

And it partially works! One and Two can slideToggle. If Two is open and One is being clicked, Two closes and when it's finished, One slideToggles open.

And this is the place where it starts to go wrong...

This

```
$('#two').slideUp(function(){
```

only lets #two to slideUp, but if #three is open, it does't close when li.one a is clicked.

I tried

```
$('#two, #tree').slideUp(function(){
```

But that gives wrong behavour.

```
$("li.one a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#two').slideUp(function(){
        $('#one').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you add your jquery as well? Anything you have tried to do and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery's animation callbacks:

```
$('#element1').slideUp(function(){
    $('#element2').slideDown();
});
```

hope that helped.